# c# unity проблемы с кодом выдает ошибку компилятор

Tags: c#, unity3d

предоставил код на кнопки,и ошибку компилятора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прочитайте сообщение об ошибке и ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО посмотрите на написание своего метода `OnPointerUP`.

Comment: ничего не понимаю .Скажите пожалуйста что исправить что бы заработало ?

Comment: У тебя крч Up с двумя заглавными буквами написан

Answer (score 0):

Исправь `public void OnPointerUP (...)` на `public void OnPointerUp (...)` - Ты сделал две заглавных буквы в UP, а надо Up